# Central Limit Theorem Proof using Logarithm Expansion

Tags: central-limit-theorem

I am trying to go over a proof of the CLT given by [this site](https://math.tutorvista.com/statistics/central-limit-theorem.html).

I understood everything up to the point where the expansion for the logarithm was used:

$$x=\frac{t^2}{2n}\ +\ \frac{t^3}{3! n^{\frac{3}{2}}}E(U_i^3).$$
This was used to expand:
$$n\ln\left(1+\frac{t^2}{2n}\ +\ \frac{t^3}{3! n^{\frac{3}{2}}}E(U_i^3)\ +\cdots\right).$$

How is this correct if the above is not in the form of $\ln(1+x)$? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logarithm of the moment generating function is

$$\ln m_u(t)=n\cdot \ln\left(1+\underbrace{\frac{t^2}{2n}\ +\ \frac{t^3}{3! n^{\frac{3}{2}}}E(U_i^3)}_{\color{red}x} +\ldots\right)$$

Now you set $x$ equal to $\frac{t^2}{2n}\ +\ \frac{t^3}{3! n^{\frac{3}{2}}}E(U_i^3) \quad (*)$

Thus you can use

$$\ln m_u(t)=n\cdot \ln\left(1+x\right)$$

Using the series expansion of $\ln(x+1)$

$$n\cdot \ln m_u(t)=n\cdot \ln\left(1+x\right)=n\cdot \left(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\ldots\right)$$

Now you insert the expression for $x$, see (*). I do it for the first three summands only.

$n\cdot \ln m_u(t)$

$$=\color{blue}n\cdot \left(\frac{t^2}{2\color{blue}n}\ +\ \frac{t^3}{3! n^{\frac{3}{2}}}E(U_i^3)-\frac{\left(\frac{t^2}{2n}\ +\ \frac{t^3}{3! n^{\frac{3}{2}}}E(U_i^3)\right)^2}{2}+\frac{\left(\frac{t^2}{2n}\ +\ \frac{t^3}{3! n^{\frac{3}{2}}}E(U_i^3)\right)^3}{3}+\ldots\right)$$

You see at the first summand $n$ is cancelling out only.

In the other cases the exponents of $n$  in the denominators are larger than 1 $\left(\frac{3}{2}, 2,  1+\frac{3}{2} , 3, ... \right)$.

Consequently for $n\to \infty$ the summands become $0$, exept the first one.

Comment: But that is exactly what I am not grasping. In the first line, it seems as if the "+..." are simply ignored. So using that substitution, wouldn't it be: $\ln(1+x+ \cdots )$? In which case (I presume) one cannot simply use the series expansion

Comment: @DylanZammit Yes the dots in the first line are ignored since the exponent of t gets larger and larger. As a result, the exponents of $n$ in the denominators are even larger.